# my date is Tue, 02 Jun 2015 02:56:20 GMT i need to convert it to month day, year

Tags: jquery, date, format

My date returning this value `Tue, 02 Jun 2015 02:56:20 GMT`. I need to show it as `June 2, 2015 14:56`. How can I do this?

```
var ipokerDateMod = ipokerAjax.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");
console.log(ipokerDateMod );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date string to UNIX time (milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) and then to a Javascript Date object to display it. It looks like the date you want is using the +1200 UTC offset so depending on how you are storing that data, you can decide how to convert.

To convert the date string to UNIX time, use `Date.parse()` (Link on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)) such as the following:

```
var milliseconds = Date.parse('Tue, 02 Jun 2015 02:56:20 GMT');
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setTime(milliseconds);
```